# HP DL380 Gen9 Top Cover Lost - Drawing

Tags: hpe

I changed datacenter and my personal is lost hp dl380 gen9 top cover. I need drawing of hp dl380 gen9. Could you please help me?

Thank you.

Best Regards...

Comment: What does this mean? "Drawing"? That doesn't make sense in context. Exactly what do you need?

Comment: BEHOLD: https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c04436999 Spare part #:777292-001

Comment: @MichaelHampton I’m assuming maybe the drawing that indicates the ram channels? That’s usually printed on the top cover. Just a guess!